# How are hybrids/cross-breeds calculated?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

We all know [half-elves](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/races.htm#halfElves), [half-orcs](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/races.htm#halfOrcs), and even [halflings](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/races.htm#halflings), though halflings don't have similar pedigree. But are there such things as half-elf half-orcs or half-halflings (quarterlings)? What about quarter-orc  three-quarters-elf? If so, what are their racial traits or how do I calculate their racial traits?

If there is (can be) no such thing, I'd love it if a fluff explanation were given, such as genetics or divine intervention.

Comment: @doppelgreener Welp, a skim-read doesn't say that they [halflings] are hybrids, so they mustn't be [relevant].

Comment: Whoops, I deleted my comment before you replied. But that phrasing could be cleared up, because right now it reads ambiguously or like you're playing on the wording. That's probably better avoided here, unless you want equally confused responses.

Comment: How about now? I do want to keep the humour in there. ^^

Comment: I think that the entry was mostly for flavour and not actually for rules, but the monster entry for mongrefolk (I think it is in MM2) writes that mongrefolks are the result of fornication of incompatible parents (other than human-orc or human-elf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There Isn't**

There's nothing in the rules for taking two races and combining them into a new race. If you want to do it, it just requires a house rule to create a new race.

Half-Elves are a funny example of it, because they don't really have a lot of things from either race. They lose the Human bonus feat & skills, they lose the Elven attribute changes. They get some other stuff that neither actually has (ie: Diplomacy bonus). It's clear that you can't come up with this list of bonuses by just combining the Human and Elven bonus list.

And that's the reason why you can't just combine whatever you want in the core rules. The "halfbreed" races aren't just cherry picking stats from either side, dividing by two, and calling it a day. They're thematically distinct, sometimes getting entirely new traits that fit the theme but don't actually come from either half.

In addition, rules to do this would be extremely complicated with the myriad of racial traits in 3.5. Making rules that explain how a 1/2 human, 1/4 Elf, 1/4 Ogre should work is awfully cumbersome, as it'd have to handle all possible combinations in a general way, and there are a ton of combinations.

So, mechanically, they don't. But nothing stops you and your DM from doing so in order to fit the specific combination you want to make. That is: there's no fluff reason why a half-Dwarf couldn't exist. They're just rare enough in a normal setting that stats for them were never created.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer since I don't know any rulebook related to this nor do I know of any known setting assessing my assumption/theory.

But here is a quite simple way you could house-rule it:

- If there is more than 50% of one race in the lineage, get the attributes of that race
- In any other cases, get human attributes.

This comes from the assumption that the human race is actually a mix of every other, which is quite understandable considering its great adaptability to the world. Thus an hybrid 1/4 Ogre, 1/4 dwarf, 1/4 elf, 1/4 orc would actually result to be a human...

Comment: If there is a native English speaker around there, please feel free to edit this and correct my mistakes ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Tridus mentions, there are no rules for this.
The only thing coming close are "half-creature" templates, though these usually involve a Level-Adjustment and just add abilities to your existing race.
Example: [Half-Fiend](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Half-Fiend)

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This is not a method that is written in any books, as mentioned in other answers, there is no official way to do this. However, this could be used as an example on how to do it yourself.**

An half orc has the following things a human does not have:

> +2 Strength, -2 Intelligence, -2 Charisma.
>
> Darkvision
>
> Counts as orc for spells that target orcs.
>
> Automatic Languages: Common and Orc. Bonus Languages: Draconic, Giant, Gnoll, Goblin, and Abyssal.
>
> Favorite class: Barbarian

Half-elves have the following things a human does not have:

> Immunity to sleep spells and similar magical effects, and a +2 racial bonus on saving throws against enchantment spells or effects.
>
> Low-Light Vision: A half-elf can see twice as far as a human in starlight, moonlight, torchlight, and similar conditions of poor illumination. She retains the ability to distinguish color and detail under these conditions.
>
> +1 racial bonus on Listen, Search, and Spot checks.
>
> +2 racial bonus on Diplomacy and Gather Information checks.
>
> Elven Blood: For all effects related to race, a half-elf is considered an elf.
>
> Automatic Languages: Common and Elven. Bonus Languages: Any (other than secret languages, such as Druidic).
>
> Favored Class: Any. When determining whether a multiclass half-elf takes an experience point penalty, her highest-level class does not count.

HOWEVER, an elf has favored class: wizard, and the any is the human flexibility shining through. Likewise, the bonus languages: any is human heritage, not elven, who instead get a different list.

**So combining those two, I'd present you with the following Orc / Elf (Olf) hybrid:**

> +2 strength, -2 intelligence, -2 charisma
>
> Darkvision out to 60 feet
>
> An olf counts as both an elf and an orc for spells that target elves or orcs.
>
> Immunity to sleep spells and similar magical effects, and a +2 racial bonus on saving throws against enchantment spells or effects.
>
> +1 racial bonus on Listen, Search, and Spot checks.
>
> Low-Light Vision: A olf can see twice as far as a human in starlight, moonlight, torchlight, and similar conditions of poor illumination. She retains the ability to distinguish color and detail under these conditions.
>
> Automatic Languages: Common, Orc and Elven. Bonus Languages: Draconic, Gnoll, Gnome, Goblin, Undercommon, Dwarven, Giant and Sylvan.
>
> Favored Class: Barbarian or Wizard

You might notice I left out the half-elf bonus to diplomacy and gather information. I did this because I feel the bonus is there to represent that an half-elf could pose as either a human or an elf, which would go a long way to getting a bonus in most circumstances. Being able to pose as a brutish elf or an effeminate orc is not really going to have quite the same result.

This is however your generic high elf template. If your olf is the son or daughter of for example a Gray Elf things become ever more complicated, because there is no template for an half-gray elf.

The end result is, I suppose, a barbarian that is pretty good at seeing things and not falling asleep.

Comment: Any particular reason you went with *olfs* (olves?) instead of *ercs*, *elcs*, or *orfs* (orves?)?

Comment: Because olf / olves sounds the funniest to me. Name it whatever you think works best. Elc might cause confusion with actual elks, but erc or orf should work just as well. I was unable to find a general consensus on what to call such a hybrid.

Answer (score -1):

This has actually been done before — the person called their [half elf/half orc race the 'voldur'](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?238557-Voldur-Half-elf-half-orc-(3-5)-If-you-read-it-you-ll-want-to-play-it-Promise). Though it doesn't take into account subraces or environmental variants, it's a great starting point and has interesting flavour. It's a homebrew, and a bit reliant on Tome of Battle, but should be easy enough to adapt to any campaign that you want to feature it in.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question; the question is broader than just a half-elf, half-orc race. I happen to recognize and like that homebrew pretty well, but it’s not really an answer to this question. And that is really important here; that may be somewhat different from what you’re used to. I recommend you check out the [Tour]—it will help with learning how this site works and is different from a discussion forum.

Comment: I have already gone through the Tour. However, though it may not have answered the whole of the question, I provided the information primarily because the questioner did specifically mention half-elf half-orcs.

So, though I could not think of anything that others have not already provided, I felt that I could at least provide an answer to what seemed to be at least one aspect. An aspect that no-one has yet addressed, far as I have been able to tell.

Comment: Unfortunately, while I may agree with your reasoning, Stack Exchange is set in its ways. In this case, your answer would be just as good as a comment. Also, I eschew homebrew.